# SQL maximum number of records with a common value

Tags: mysql, sql

Please consider the following two tables:

```
Holidays
HolidayID (PK)
Destination
Length
MaximumNumber
...


Bookings
BookingID  (PK)
HolidayID (FK)
Name
...
```

Customers can book holidays (e.g. go to Hawaii). But, suppose that a given holiday has a maximum number of places. e.g. there are only 75 holidays to Hawaii this year (ignoring other years).

So if some customer wants to book a holiday to Hawaii. I need to count the records in Bookings table, and if that number is greater than 75 I have to tell the customer it's too late.
This I can do using 2 MySQL queries (1 to get MaximumNumber for the holiday, 2 to get the current total from Bookings) and PHP (for example) to compare the count value with the maximum number of Hawaii holidays.
But I want to know if there is a way to do this purely in SQL (MySQL in this case)? i.e. count the number of bookings for Hawaii and compare against Hawaii's MaximumNumber value.

EDIT:
My method:

```
$query1 = "SELECT MaximumNumber FROM Holidays WHERE HolidayID=$hawaiiID";

$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(BookingID) FROM Bookings WHERE HolidayID=$hawaiiID";
```

So if the first query gives 75 and the second query gives 75 I can compare these values in PHP. But I wondered if there was a way to do this somehow in SQL alone.

Comment: better give : 1-what have you tried ,2- simple data , 3-wished output , 4 - sqlfiddle if possible ,5-write your code formatted , 6- .... ...... 10- we can help you easilly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but why not use a subquery to determine the total bookings for each holidayid:

```
select *
from holidays h
left join
(
  select count(*) TotalBooked, HolidayId
  from bookings
  group by holidayId
) b
  on h.holidayId = b.holidayId
WHERE h.HolidayID=$hawaiiID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52fe7/5).

Then you could use a `CASE` expression to compare the `TotalBooked` to the `MaxNumber` similar to this:

```
select h.destination,
  case 
    when b.totalbooked = h.maxNumber
    then 'Not Available'
    else 'You can still book' end Availability
from holidays h
left join
(
  select count(*) TotalBooked, HolidayId
  from bookings
  group by holidayId
) b
  on h.holidayId = b.holidayId
WHERE h.HolidayID=$hawaiiID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52fe7/6).

You will notice that I used a `LEFT JOIN` which will return all rows from the `Holidays` table even if there are not matching rows in the `Bookings` table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.  You can fill in the details:

```
select case 
when 
(select count(*) 
from Bookings 
where holidayID = $hawaiiid) 
<= MaximumNumber then 'available' else 'sold out' end status
from holidays 
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
select case when b.freq < h.MaximumNumber
            then 'Available'
            else 'Not Available'
            end as MyResult
from Holidays h
left join (
   select HolidayID
        , count(*) as freq
   from Bookings
   where HolidayID=$hawaiiID
   group by HolidayID
   ) b
on h.HolidayID=b.HolidayID
```